# Apply Number formatting to Pandas HTML CSS Styling

Tags: python, css, pandas

In Pandas, there is a new styler option for formatting CSS ( http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.core.style.Styler.html ).

Before, when I wanted to make my numbers into accounting/dollar terms, I would use something like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'10/01/2015': {'Issued': 200}}, orient='index')
html = df.to_html(formatters={'Issued': format_money})
```

format_money function:

```
def format_money(item):
    return '${:,.0f}'.format(item)
```

Now I want to use the Style options, and keep my $ formatting. I'm not seeing any way to do this.

Style formatting for example would be something like this:

```
    s = df.style.bar(color='#009900')
    #df = df.applymap(config.format_money) -- Doesn't work
    html = s.render()
```

This would add bars to my HTML table like so(Docs here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html):

[image: from http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html]

So basically, how do I do something like add the bars, and keep or also add in the dollar formatting to the table? If I try to do it before, the Style bars don't work because now they can't tell that the data is numerical and it errors out. If I try to do it after, it cancels out the styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That hasn't been implemented yet (version 0.17.1) - but there is a pull request for that (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/11667) and should come out in 0.18. For now you have to stick to using the formatters.

Comment: Well how would I use the formatters in this case? Or are you saying stick to using the formatters in terms of I cannot do both?

Comment: stick to using just the formatters for now - I don't see a way to work around this issue for now - I guess the `.bar` and `highlight_min`, `highlight_max` etc. should all take `kwargs` for the column data formats, could you file an issue for that on github.com/pydata/pandas so that the maintainers can track it, maybe link the `PR` from my answer to the issue as well.